# The selected icon in the bottom bar does not change

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried a couple of options to make my icon change when it's clicked. But none of the options worked. She's just dyed blue.

Here is my first choice -

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage('assets/images/home.PNG')
                  ), 
                  activeIcon: ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage('assets/images/home_color.PNG')
                  ),
                  label: "Главная",
                ),
```

And here is the second option -

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: selectedIndex == 0 ? ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage('assets/images/home.PNG')
                  ) : ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/images/home_color.PNG')
                      ),
                  // activeIcon: ImageIcon(
                  //     AssetImage('assets/images/home_color.PNG')
                  // ),
                  label: "Главная",
                ),
```

Tell me what's wrong

Here are the settings I use for the bottombar itself -

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: selectedIndex,
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
```

And full code bottom bar - https://dpaste.org/SuHuk

Comment: can you paste full bottombar code.

Comment: @ManishDayma ready

Comment: code is fine are your assets loading perfectly ?

Comment: Yes, everything works well, except for activeIcon

Comment: change of tab is working properly with selectedIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `ImageIcon` with `Image.asset`:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Image.asset("assets/inactive_icon.png"),
    label: label,
    activeIcon: Image.asset("assets/active_icon.png"),
  );
```